# Draw cubic bezier curves in Actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics, bezier

What's the best way to draw cubic bezier curves programmatically in AS3? The `Graphics` class only seems to support quadratic curves. :( I want to be able to do something like:

```
var startPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);
var endPoint:Point = new Point(5, 5);
var control1:Point = new Point(5, 0);
var control2:Point = new Point(0, 5);

var myBezier:Sprite = getBezier(startPoint, control1, control2, endPoint);
```

For a performance target, I'm planning on having ~50 of these on the stage at once.

Comment: This page contains a python version of [cubicToQuadratic](http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/laserprop/client/SVGPath.py) It won't be hard to translate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** Flash Player 11 onwards includes a native method to draw cubic curves, [cubicCurveTo()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#cubicCurveTo%28%29) which should be the fastest method if you are targeting FP11.

Just last week I wrote a class to draw Bezier curves of arbitrary order.

The code is not optimized but works fine in my tests. Performance is acceptable event for doing animations (although I don't think it's a good idea to abuse it, since as I said it's not optimized; it doesn't make sense to use these for quadratic curves, of course, since the player can do that natively).

The code is here if you want to use it or take a look:

[The BezierCurve class](http://gist.github.com/470095)

[Sample code](http://gist.github.com/470097)

I think that with the sample code you will be able to figure out how to use it without trouble (it's quite straight forward and somewhat commented); but if you run into problems, ask away!

Feel free to use it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If quadratic are built into that API call, you'll have to understand Bezier well enough to write your own cubic implementation.

Like [this](http://www.paultondeur.com/2008/03/09/drawing-a-cubic-bezier-curve-using-actionscript-3/).

Answer (score 0):

This site lists and explains various ways of approximating cubic Bezier curves :
http://timotheegroleau.com/Flash/articles/cubic_bezier_in_flash.htm

At the very bottom he gives a method with the heading **Fixed MidPoint approach** which uses four quadratic curves as an approximation and seems to be the best in terms of accuracy and performance out of all the methods.