# Random bezier blob?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, bezier

I have some ActionScript3 code I'm using to create liquid-like "droplets", and when they're first generated they look like a curved square (that's as close as I can get them to being a circle). I've tried and failed a lot here but my goal is to make these droplets look more organic and free-form, as if you were looking closely at rain drops on your windshield before they start dripping.

Here's what I have:

```
var size:int       = (100 - asset.width) / 4,
    droplet:Shape  = new Shape();

droplet.graphics.beginFill(0xCC0000);
droplet.graphics.moveTo(size / 2, 0);
droplet.graphics.curveTo(size, 0, size, size / 2);
droplet.graphics.curveTo(size, size, size / 2, size);
droplet.graphics.curveTo(0, size, 0, size / 2);
droplet.graphics.curveTo(0, 0, size / 2, 0);

// Apply some bevel filters and such...
```

Which yields a droplet shaped like this:

[image: Droplet example]

When I try adding some randomness to the size or the integers or add more curves in the code above, I end up getting jagged points and some line overlap/inversion.

I'm really hoping someone who is good at math or bezier logic can see something obvious that I need to do to make my consistently rounded-corner square achieve shape randomness similar to this:

[image: Water droplet example]

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251254/draw-cubic-bezier-curves-in-actionscript it says FP11 has a cubic curve draw method, so you can at least draw a non-jagged shape of bezier curves. After you'll do this, you will be able to get some better randomness, including a little sharper angles or jagged points with no overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can get actual circle-looking cirles using beziers by using `0.55228 * size` rather than half-size (in relation to bezier curves, this is sometimes called kappa). It only applies if you're using four segments, and that's where the other hint comes in: the more points you have, the more you can make your shape "creep", so you might actually want more segments, in which case it becomes easier to simply generate a number of points on a circle (fairly straight forward using good old sine and cosine functions and a regularly spaced angle), and then come up with the multi-segment Catmul-Rom curve through those points instead. Catmul-Rom curves and Bezier curves are actually different representations of the same curvatures, so you can pretty much trivially convert from one to the other, explained over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv (last item in the section gives the translation if you don't care about the maths). You can then introduce as much random travel as you want (make the upper points a little stickier and "jerk" them down when they get too far from the bottom points to get that sticky rain look)